# Kivy+Camera+Ubuntu error with v4l2src

Tags: python

I'm trying to write an simple app to show camera view on app window(live stream) by using kivy on ubuntu. I used code from this website http://karanbalkar.com/2012/10/tutorial-6-working-with-camera-in-kivy/ . Compiler shows error like this : GError: no element "v4l2src"

I'm completly fresh in Ubuntu and Python programming and simply does not understand what is wrong :D

There is whole code:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window

class MyApp(App):
    def doscreenshot(self,*largs):
        Window.screenshot(name='screenshot%(counter)04d.jpg')

    def build(self):
        camwidget = Widget()
        cam = Camera() 
        cam = Camera(resolution=(640,480),size=(500,500))
        cam.play=True 
        camwidget.add_widget(cam)

        button = Button(text='screenshot',size_hint=(0.12,0.12))
        button.bind(on_press=self.doscreenshot)
        camwidget.add_widget(button)

        return camwidget

if __name__ == '__main__':`enter code here`
    MyApp().run()
```

IDLE debugger:

```
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/maciek/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-03-01_13.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] [Camera      ] Provider: pygst
[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <3.0 Mesa 11.0.2>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Intel Open Source Technology Center>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile >
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Shading version <1.30>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO              ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO              ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/maciek/testcamera.py", line 27, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 802, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "/home/maciek/testcamera.py", line 16, in build
     cam = Camera(resolution=(640,480),size=(500,500))
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/camera.py", line 91, in __init__
     on_index()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/camera.py", line 103, in _on_index
     resolution=self.resolution, stopped=True)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/camera/camera_pygst.py", line 46, in __init__
     super(CameraPyGst, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/camera/__init__.py", line 70, in __init__
     self.init_camera()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/camera/camera_pygst.py", line 64, in init_camera
     self._pipeline = gst.parse_launch(pl % (video_src, GL_CAPS))
 GError: no element "v4l2src"
```

Comment: Please edit your post so that it contains the sample of code that generates the Exception (error)

Comment: I figured out that when i put an comment on line with setting camera resolution it returns an error :/